# Madvertise 404 error and "Code has to be installed"

Tags: android

I'm testing madvertise. So I registered an account at the web site, downloaded the sdk and the sample code, registered an app in the web, and in the sample code changed

```
    <meta-data android:value="TestTokn" android:name="madvertise_site_token" />
```

for

```
    <meta-data android:value="MYAPPTOKEN" android:name="madvertise_site_token" />
```

And the response for this token is always a 404 and in the website the app appears as "Code has to be installed"

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for registering with madvertise. The "MYAPPTOKEN" is only a placeholder for the token you get when signing up at madvertise. You can find this token in your profile: Log in at madvertise.com, click on "Websites & Apps" -> "Overview" and then on your app. You should see something like in the screenshot (linked below, location of the token is encircled in red).

[image]

In case you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to contact us!